# Using if statement in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column containing prices of product

[image]

I'm trying to to create a script that for all products that cost 2000 and more it must display a phrase 'sum of expensive product' and the total value if no product that cost 2000 or more exist then for all product that cost less than 1000 it must display a phrase 'sum of cheap products' and total value

I tried this but it's not working

```
DECLARE @PRICE INT

SELECT @PRICE = PRICE 
FROM Product

IF @PRICE >= 2000
BEGIN
    PRINT 'SUM OF EXPENSIVE PRODUCT'+ SUM(@PRICE)       
END
ELSE
    IF @PRICE <= 100
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'SOME OF CHEAP PRODUCTS'+SUM(@PRICE)
    END
```

Result should be like

[image]

Comment: The Problem here: 

SELECT @PRICE=PRICE FROM Product

Because the return result is more than value

The Error: 

An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

The Solution:
Return one value via using SUM function

Comment: Your example output is not correct as far as I can see. There are two products with a value greater than 2000: fridge freezer (3512) and deep freeze (2999). The total of these two items is 6511, not 5999

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see that.if i could just get how to solve the question. the answer doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a straight `IF ELSE` block:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Product WHERE PRICE >= 2000)
    SELECT 'SUM OF EXPENSIVE PRODUCTS: '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), (SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM Product WHERE PRICE >= 2000))
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Product WHERE PRICE >= 1000)
    SELECT 'SUM OF CHEAP PRODUCTS: '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), (SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM Product));
```

Comment: You are missing a where clause in your `SUM`. At the moment you will total _all_ products irrespective of the price being above or below 2000. All you are changing is the text displayed.

Comment: Updated to reflect my  current understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's query to get what you want...

```
select
  sum(case when Price >= 2000 then Price else 0 end) as [Sum of Expensive Products],
  sum(case when Price < 1000 then Price else 0 end) as [Sum of Cheap Products]
into #T 
from Product

declare @xPrice decimal (9, 2) = (select [Sum of Expensive Products] from #t);
print 'SUM OF EXPENSIVE PRODUCT: ' + convert(varchar(50), @xPrice);

--Repeat for cheap...

drop table #T;
```

If you want this as a normal result set (e.g. not printing the result), just modify the first query and remove `into #T`.

Answer (score 0):

The query below should give you the original product list with prices, along with the expensive/inexpensive total prices and appropriate labels.

```
SELECT Name,
       Price,
       CASE WHEN price >= 2000 THEN 'SUM OF EXPENSIVE PRODUCTS'
                               ELSE 'SOME OF CHEAP PRODUCTS'
       END AS label,
       CASE WHEN price >= 2000 THEN (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.Price >= 2000 THEN p.Price ELSE 0 END)
        FROM Product p)
            ELSE (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.Price < 2000 THEN p.Price ELSE 0 END)
        FROM Product p)
       END AS total
FROM Product
```

Comment: is there a way of using IF instead of when?

Comment: `IF` is not available as far as I know.  Any reason why you can't use `CASE`?

Comment: Its a school work.the marking sheet said use IF statement.i'll try the way @sokuai did it